# What alternative browser rendering engines exist for Linux/UNIX?

Tags: linux, browser, rendering

Now that Opera has switched to WebKit too, on Linux I found only WebKit or Gecko based browsers. The only other one was KDE/Konqueror's KHTML and on Windows IE's Trident. Are there any other alternatives to WebKit and Gecko on Linux?

Comment: Interesting question and now I'd like to know the answer. Still... even a more interesting question is why do you want another one? Lack of features? Just curiosity?

Comment: Just curiosity.

Comment: I am sure others exist.  Opera didn't switch to Chronium they switched to a different rendering engine the underline browser is still Opera. I don't believe there is anything really except WebKit, Gecko,  and Trident in the Windows world.  Within the Linux world thats different since Trident isn't even an option.

Comment: Opera did it, they switched and started commiting to WebKit and Chromium. They even switched to v8.

Comment: WebKit of course was a fork of KHTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Wikipedia article titled [Comparison of layout engines (HTML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML%29) which may be useful.  Aside from [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29), [KHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KHTML), [Trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29), and [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit), there is **[Presto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_%28layout_engine%29)**, **[Amaya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaya_%28web_browser%29)**, and **[Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_%28web_browser%29)** - although they are far from being as widely used as the previously mentioned rendering engines.  A more complete list of graphical HTML rendering engines [can be found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_layout_engines)

There also exists [text-based web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_web_browser) (usually with command-line interfaces).  Two notable examples are **[Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29)** and **[ELinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELinks)**.